# How can I turn off host name resolutios?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I posted a question: [SocketException is thrown when i call my web application from distance client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228439/socketexception-is-thrown-when-i-call-my-web-application-from-distance-client).
Someone tell me to turn off host name resolutions. How can I turn off this?